# LinkedList Destructor Style

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

Given my following header:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include "ListEle.h"
class List{
private: ListEle* data;
         const List* next;
public:  List(ListEle* d, List* n):data(d),next(n){}
         ~List(){
             if(data!=nullptr)delete data;
             if(next!=nullptr)delete next;
         }
};
#endif
```

Is it correct that my list will recursively delete itself?

Then i've read a few threads stating that using recursive destructors (for lists) will eventually spam my stack. So i searched for an alternative and found examples like this:

```
~List(){
 delete data;
 List* delptr = next;
  while(delptr!=nullptr){
  List* temp = delptr->next;
  delete delptr;
  delptr = temp;
  }
}
```

If my thoughts are correct the 2nd example is also somehow recursive because of the "delete delptr" line. My idea is that delete delptr calls the destructor of my next list-item which will create a "delptr" as well and continues to call the destructors for the next items. therefor my stack should look similar to my first example. i'm pretty sure there might be a mistake in my understanding of deleting objects. at the moment i feel like my while loop in the 2nd example is quite unnecessary.

Hope that someone might help me clear up my situation,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that it is unnecessary to check a pointer for null before passing it to `delete`. The latter does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your list will recursively delete itself. However, you can't do that if you want to delete a single entry in the middle of the list, because then all elements after that will also be deleted.

You have the same problem, and others, with the other destructor as well. And it will still be recursive.

It will be easier if you make a small change in your design, and use *two* classes: One for the actual list, and one for the nodes in the list. Then let the list handle all removal/deleting of nodes, and keep the node structure as simple as possible (only the data and a `next` pointer, no functions except a constructor that initializes the data and next pointers).